# java (jdbc, ms sql server) how to get an indication that my query was executed?

Tags: java, jdbc

My application does queries to database (non-queries too).

I show to the user indeterminate progressbar while transaction.

The problem is that I don't know when to close the progressbar, because I have no indication or signal object of query completion.

Comment: Depends on how you show the progress bar. Swing? JSP? JSF? Etc. So more detail in the question is welcome.

Comment: Can you give more details? By default you of course know when a database query is finished. So my guess is that the problem is really specific to your architecture and applicaton.

Comment: I use Swing component in a different thread, and I think it's just not right to use ResultSet object (for example) to determine whether the transaction is done.

Answer (score 2):

If your queries are taking so long that you need a progress bar, I'd recommend taking a hard look at your database to see how you can speed them up.

Since a database operation blocks, you know it's done when you return.

The progress bar suggests that you need some kind of polling mechanism to check a metric that indicates how much you have to do and how many have been done.  Since you don't give any details, I can only guess what those might be.

But an AJAX call in your JSP to poll and update the progress bar is most likely what you need.